# How do I check how much free space is on my usb stick? (Kubuntu 18.04)

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin

How do I check how much free space is on my usb? I don't see how I can do this, although I can access the usb stick's files when I insert it through Dolphin. Preferably a UI option, not command line.

Comment: Take a look to these answers too - [How do I find the amount of free space on my hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/q/73160/66509).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look in the lower right corner of the Dolphin screen after you've inserted the USB stick. In the example, my USB stick has 3.7 GiB free.

[image: free space on USB stick]

If you don't see anything like that, open Dolphin, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to bring up `Dolphin Preferences`. In there, click on `General` in the left pane and then on the `Status Bar` tab and ensure that `Show Space Information` is active.

[image: Dolphin Preferences]

Dolphin also allows you to examine the USB stick's properties. With the device inserted, move up to `root` and then to `media`. Open `media`. There you'll see, possibly among other folders, a folder with *your* username. Open that: you should see a folder bearing your USB stick's name (as seen by Dolphin). Right-click on that folder to get the window shown below. The `General` tab will show you what you want.

[image: usb-properties]

And, I know you asked for a route using the graphical interface but you can get the basic information, somewhat quicker, using the command line. See the last line in the output below on running `df -h`:

```
dkb@kububb:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           785M  1.6M  784M   1% /run
/dev/sda6       288G   26G  248G  10% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       496M   34M  463M   7% /boot/efi
tmpfs           785M     0  785M   0% /run/user/118
tmpfs           785M  4.0K  785M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           785M   12K  785M   1% /run/user/1001
/dev/sdb1       466G  196G  271G  43% /media/dkb/TOSHIBA EXT
```

Comment: Does "filled in with colour" denote "active"? (In the UIs I'm familiar with, a filled-in checkbox denotes "active for some of the items selected".)

Comment: @MathieuK. please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047875/half-selected-effect-in-kubuntu

Comment: Thanks @DKBose for taking the time to answer my question!